# Why is stopPropagation required for mousewheel click

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In the content script of my Firefox Addon I have the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var t = event.target;
  var nearestATag = t.nodeName === 'A'
    ? t
    : findParentByTagName(t, 'A');
  if (nearestATag !== undefined) {
    self.port.emit('click-link', nearestATag.getAttribute('href'));
  }
});
```

I want to prevent the URL from opening in the panel where the script is running and open it in the new browser's tab instead.

It works perfectly in case of a left mouse click, but doesn't work as expected in case of mousewheel click -- URL opens twice, so it seems that `preventDefault` doesn't do anything here.

Adding `event.stopPropagation();` after `event.stopPropagation();` works but I don't really understand why.

So can you help me understand why?